# Why I am not getting any output for jsonObject.getString("weather")?

Tags: java, android, json

```
 protected void onPostExecute(String s)
        {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            log.i("URL" , s) // I am getting output for this part
            try
                {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s); // JSONObject Created
                    String weatherInfo = jsonObject.getString("weather"); // Fetching info from weather section

                    Log.i("JSON", urlResult); // But not for this part

                    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(weatherInfo);
                    for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++)
                    {
                        JSONObject jsonPart = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Not getting output for this two lines also
                        Log.i("main", jsonPart.getString("main")); // fetching info from 'main' section
                        Log.i("description", jsonPart.getString("description"));  // fetching info from 'description' section
                    }
                }
            catch (Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace(); // Handling Error
                }
        }
```

I am trying to fetch weather info from openworldmap.org. I am using Android Studio 3.0. URL that I am passing into code is  https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22

Comment: I ran this code with the string you linked and it outputs correctly for "main" and "description". What is urlResult that you're logging, isn't it supposed to be "weatherInfo"?

Comment: Yes, my fault. But passing weatherInfo also giving me no result

Answer (score 1):

You can call getJSONArray,

```
//String weatherInfo = jsonObject.getString("weather"); // Fetching info from weather section

//Log.i("JSON", urlResult); // But not for this part
//JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(weatherInfo);
JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("weather");
```

and in the for loop you should use get(i);

```
JSONObject jsonPart = jsonArray.get(i); //jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
```

Comment: It is still not working, W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value null of type org.json.JSONObject$1 cannot be converted to JSONObject
        at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
        at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:163)
        at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:176)    This are the errors, I am getting

Comment: @SanketGanorkar, your way to access to the an item in the array has bug, use jsonArray.get(i),